# how to fix SEVERE: Servlet /Rest threw load() exception

Tags: java, rest, servlets

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Rest</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>pkg.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

here is my web.xml file when i run project and upload: Servlet /Rest threw load() exception in Logcat please help me while I had put all jersey jar file I do not understand where am I doing mistake!